# Java Beginner looking for Guidance

Tags: java

I have no idea what I'm doing. Please help me!

I'm supposed to:

Add a method named printEmployeeInfo to the class Employee which will print the information about the employee – name, employee number and current salary.

Create an application class EmployeeDemo (similar to the class DeclareTwoEmployee) which creates two objects of the type Employee, sets the values of their data fields and prints their information by calling printEmployeeInfo method.

```
Public class Employee {     // an application class
public static void main( String[] args) { 
}
```

Comment: Help you with what, _specifically_?

Comment: Btw public should be lowercase

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Employee {
private String name;
private String number ;
private String current_salary;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getCurrent_salary() {
    return current_salary;
}

public void setCurrent_salary(String current_salary) {
    this.current_salary = current_salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" + "name=" + name + ", number=" + number + ", current_salary=" + current_salary + '}';
}

public void printEmployeeInfo()
{
    System.out.println(this);
}
public static void main( String[] args) { 
    Employee e=new Employee();
    e.setCurrent_salary("0");
    e.setName("Lura Schiele");
    e.setNumber("000-000-000");
    e.printEmployeeInfo();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create an employee class with name, employee number and current salary. So to your class add those three fields like:

```
public class Employee {
    String employeeName; 
    String employeeNumber;
    double salary;
    //declare printEmployeeInfo method like
    public void printEmployeeInfo() {
        System.out.println(employeeName....);
    }
}
```

And the create Demo class with main method in it like:

```
class EmployeeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Employee e1 = ..//first employee
         Employee e2 = ..//second employee instance
         e1.printEmployeeInfo();//calling method which will print employee info
    }
}
```